# Convert bottom up microsoft Bitmap to top down Android format

Tags: android, c++, bitmap, java-native-interface

I'm using a c++ capture card driver that provides me some bitmaps in the Microsoft format(bottom up). I'm sending the bitmap as an array to android through jni and using this to draw the bitmap in android.

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(1920, 1080, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(m_data);
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dstRect, null);
```

The image is upside down and from right to left.
Any ideas how to fix this without flipping the android bitmap?

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure you cannot draw the bitmap using a custom conversion matrix? The alternative is very CPU-, memory- and battery-intensive and will probably not achieve 60fps.

Comment: apparently,  there was an option in my driver to select between the microsoft format and the normal one.

Comment: If `m_data` can be an **int** array, you can pass it to [createBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config))